# How to delete and disable logs for an Amazon RDS SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a minuscule Amazon RDS instance running SQL Server and its storage almost reached the maximum allowed free tier storage of 20GB.

I have read that this might be due to the db logs. I am only using the db to get acquainted to RDS so I don't think I need any logs at the moment.

But I cannot find a way to remove the logs, nor to disable them so that the size will not increase back.

There is a [way to view them or download them](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Logs.html#Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Logs.SP), but not to remove or disable.

For other types of db engines, like [MySQL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html), AWS does provide a way to remove them, by calling the rotation procedure twice in a row. Is there a similar way for SQL Server engines?

Comment: It appears that you can change the retention period... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.SQLServer.html

Comment: Indeed, but that only works for trace and dump logs, not for the error or agent ones...

Comment: True, but you can download the other logs to confirm whether they are large, like you suspect.

Comment: Yes :). And they are all KB-sized. From the doc you referenced: *"For security reasons, you cannot delete a specific trace or dump file on a SQL Server DB instance. To delete all unused trace or dump files, set the retention period for the files to 0."* - and there's my answer.

If you post the comment as an answer I'll accept it.